# form inside angular modal not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {
    'use strict'
    angular
        .module('inspinia')
        .controller('myController', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$uibModal'];
    function myController($scope, $uibModal) {

        function openModal() {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'my_path/modal.html',
                scope: $scope
            });
        };

    }
})();
```

I have a button that opens the modal when calling `openModal`.

Here is my modal template:

```
<div class="inmodal" ng-controller="modalController">
    <div class="row">
        <form name="myForm" ng-submit="processForm()" ng-validate="" class="p-lg">
            <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the problem: when I open the modal with the `form` tag inside it I don't get the template that I'm expecting, I'm getting the page from where I am inside the modal. But when I comment the entire form, everything goes OK, but I need this form :)

What could be going on? There are no errors been shown in the console.

---

```
<div class="inmodal" ng-controller="modalController">
    <div class="row">
        <!--<form name="myForm" ng-submit="processForm()" ng-validate="" class="p-lg">
            <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
        </form>-->
    </div>
</div>
```

That works.

---

I'm new with angular. If any info is missing, please tell me :)

[That's the modal I'm using.](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.6.1/Angular/#/miscellaneous/modal_window)

---

**EDIT**

Actually, the problem is with `<div id="form-views" ui-view></div>`, this `div` is used with this [wizard](http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v2.6.1/Angular/#/forms/wizard/step_one).

Comment: I have an awful feeling this has to do with scopes.

Comment: Protip: stop using `ng-controller` completely. Seriously, never use it. Use components instead (or directives with `restrict: E` and `scope: {}` if you're on an earlier version of Angular) This'll help you avoid scope issues.